# Change Theme.Dialog to look like Theme.Light.Dialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes

There is no `Theme.Light.Dialog` to use with the rest of my project that is using `Theme.Light`.

How can I change `Theme.Dialog` to look like a `Theme.Light` version of `Dialog`.

I know that I must overwrite sections of `Theme.Dialog` in styles.xml as below. What items should I overwrite with which values?

```
<style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:???????"></item>
    <item name="android:???????"></item>
</style>
```

I could just make the background that light white grey, but the buttons, spinners etc are also different on the light theme to look better on the light background.

**EDIT**

Looks like I got it working.

```
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="whitegrey">#FFF2F2F2</color>

<style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="@android:windowBackground">@color/whitegrey</item>
    <item name="@android:textColor">@color/black</item>        
</style>
```

Comment: Try [this](http://pastie.org/4037973) one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like I got it working.

```
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="whitegrey">#FFF2F2F2</color>

<style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="@android:windowBackground">@color/whitegrey</item>
    <item name="@android:textColor">@color/black</item>        
</style>
```

Comment: You would assign it to an activity inside your manifest to make it look like a dialogue. ( android:theme="@style/dialog_light" )

Comment: You can also pass , R.style.yourstyle as second argument while creating instance of Dialog

Answer (score 9):

Further to the above, to avoid making up colors, I did this:

```
<!-- Makes a "light" equivalent of Theme.Dialog -->
<style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="@android:background">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="@android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>    
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is good, thanks!
I just changed it a bit: when I run what you suggested, the entire screen is painted with the back color and the dialog does not look as it should (with the previous activity dimmed).

So instead of using

```
@android:windowBackground
```

just use

```
@android:background
```