# Progress Dialog without padding

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a simple Progress Dialog generator method inside a `Fragment`:

```
public void showProgressDialog(int messageId){
    String message = getString(messageId);
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getActivity(), "", message, true);
}
```

My Progress Dialog appears like this, without that normal padding:
[image: Progress Dialog]

What should I do to have that default padding around my progress bar?

EDIT: Adding themes.xml file

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <!-- Toolbar Theme / Apply white arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarTheme</item>

    <!-- Material Theme -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>

    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- White arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/drawerArrowColor</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

> This class was deprecated in API level 26. ProgressDialog is a modal
>   dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead
>   of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like
>   ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively,
>   you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress. For more details [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog)

Comment: I guess its because you are not passing `title` value. why not give it an appropriate title. or try passing `"  "` instead of `""`

Comment: Tried with title also, no success...

Comment: are you running this on `android M`? did you tried in another versions?

Comment: Not on android M, but I'm using `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` and `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as my application parent theme, maybe it's the theme?

Comment: try using this style `"@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Comment: Sorry @KaranMer, didn't get it. You want me to use this style where exatcly?

Comment: use this style as parent for your progressdialog style in `styles.xml` see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915492/change-theme-dialog-to-look-like-theme-light-dialog-in-android

Comment: @KayanAlmeida would your problem solved ?

Comment: No @dex, sorry :( It happened only in this project... i've made some other apps and Everything worked fine

Comment: @KayanAlmeida I was able to solve this problem. If you required the solution I will share.

Comment: In my case problem was in `android:fitsSystemWindows=true` in activity theme. I changed it to false, and progress had default paddings

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution method,create a new theme for the Dialog. Hope it will help you!

```
   <style name="ProgressDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
    </style>

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ProgressDialogTheme);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setMessage(content);
    progressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
 pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
           // (To customize your dialog)pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuu can try below code:

```
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), getTheme());
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.pleaseWait));
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.message));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
```

You can set different theme for your progressdialog..

> 1) Try ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK instead of getTheme().
>
> 2) Or you can set custom theme. See thi [link](http://dtmilano.blogspot.in/2010/01/android-ui-colored-dialogs.html) .

For more details. See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It didn't work... I guess it has something to do with my theme

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` in my app theme. Deleting this item helped me (actually, just moved it in other parts of my code).