# Changing text color of AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I have an AlertDialog that contains two options for the user to click on. The AlertDialog is working as intended but I can't figure out how to change the text color from black to white:

[image]

This is the code:

```
String[] shareOptions = {"Copy media url", "Copy Reddit url"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(),R.style.AlertDialogDark));
builder.setItems(shareOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        String copiedUrl = "";
        if(which == 0) copiedUrl = mCurrSubmission.getUrl();
        else copiedUrl = "www.reddit.com" + mCurrSubmission.getPermalink();

        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("share_url", copiedUrl);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
});
builder.show();
return true;
```

This is the style I am trying to use:

```
<style name="AlertDialogDark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorDarkerGray</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

How do I change the text color from black to white?

Comment: Are you using a custom layout for the AlertDialog?

Comment: No. I've included everything relevant here

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

`<item name="@android:textColor">#ffffff</item>`

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946076/6439134), the developer used it with @. maybe it effects.

Answer (score 0):

This code customizes the dialog's message:

```
AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
TextView messageView = ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageView.setTextColor(0xffffff);
messageView.setText("your title");
```

The standard dialog's message is a `TextView` with id: `android.R.id.message`. 
 
Since the message is a `TextView` you can make further customizations, like the background color, the padding etc.
 
After this code you can call:

```
ad.show();
```